# Magento 2 creditmemo items getting twice in $creditMemo->getAllItems();

Tags: magento2

Magento credit memo items details getting twice.how to avoid this problem anyone help me

Comment: If you are getting thrm double it seems you have configurable and simple products in your original order right? If so try to use `$creditMemo->getVisibleItems();` instead. If it doesn't work, inside your foreach browsing collection, use `if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue;`

Comment: I already try this method but that time foreach content not getting.i got an error like this

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/dev-webstore.family.qa/app/code/Custom/Learning/Controller/Page/Test.php on line 253

Comment: Can you please write your code on you description?